# How can I update scale at runtime on Image in WPF?

Tags: wpf, runtime, scaling

i'm having some issues updating the scale of an image dynamically in WPF. The exact behavior that I want is when I click on a button, i'd like to scale up (or down) the image inside the UserControl.

My XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Company.Scaling.ScaleControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="imageContainer" Stretch="None" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform">
            </ScaleTransform>
        </Image.LayoutTransform>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

I'm currently updating the properties ScaleX and ScaleY like this:

```
this.scaleTransform.ScaleX = this.ZoomScale;
this.scaleTransform.ScaleY = this.ZoomScale;
```

It works when i'm updating these in the constructor of my XAML like this:

```
public ScaleControl()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.ZoomScale = 1.5f;
}
```

But when i'm updating these properties on Runtime (after I click the button) it does not work.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for the help!

Edit:

After what Clemens said, I've add a few things.

Bindings in the XAML:

```
<Image.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform
                ScaleX="{Binding ZoomScale, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                ScaleY="{Binding ZoomScale, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
        </Image.LayoutTransform>
```

A dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoomScaleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ZoomScale", typeof(double), typeof(ScaleControl));
```

and the property:

```
public double ZoomScale
{
    get { return (double)this.GetValue(ZoomScaleProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(ZoomScaleProperty, value); }
}
```

I'm pretty new to WPF so maybe I am missing something again but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Are you changing `ZoomScale` when the button is clicked?

Comment: Yes i'm doing: this.ZoomScale = 1.6 and Nothing happens

Comment: I would suggest using Clemens answer of making a DependencyProperty of ZoomScale and setting it through that. Setting ZoomScale once during the constructor will not update the values through runtime

Comment: It should work now. How are you changing the ZoomLevel property?

Comment: For now, I have a method that is triggered by a button click that set the ZoomScale to 2 instead of 1. I'm sorry, I feel like a complete novice..

Comment: Finally, it works, the problem was from another place. Actually, I have a panel that includes this wpf layout, but I was referencing to this view but doing a new ScaleControl() so the reference wasn't good. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the ZoomScale property will not magically update the ScaleTransform's ScaleX and ScaleY properties, only because you have previously assigned ZoomScale to their values.

You'll have to *bind* the ScaleTransform properties to ZoomScale, e.g. like this:

```
<Image ...>
    <Image.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform
            ScaleX="{Binding ZoomScale,
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
            ScaleY="{Binding ZoomScale,
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
    </Image.LayoutTransform>
</Image>
```

See [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview) for details.

In addition, the ZoomScale property must notify about value changes. In a class derived from DependencyObject, you would usually declare it as dependency property, like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoomScaleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ZoomScale", typeof(double), typeof(ScaleControl));

public double ZoomScale
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(ZoomScaleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ZoomScaleProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, i think i've added the right thing in:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ScalingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ZoomScale", typeof(float), typeof(UserControl));
```

and

```
public float ZoomScale { get { return (float)GetValue(ScalingProperty); } set { SetValue(ScalingProperty, value); } }
```

for the dependency property. Also i've added:

```
ScaleX="{Binding ZoomScale, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

in my XAML but nothing seems to scale..

Comment: Please don't write an answer. Edit your question instead. And carefully read the property declaration in my answer. The property type should be `double` and the third argument to Register *must* be `typeof(ScaleControl)` (or whatever the derived UserControl class actually is).

Comment: Yes sorry, i'm pretty new to StackOverflow, so i've edited my first question to add a few things.

Comment: Useless answers should remove from communications .